# gemfile syntax error: bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle-install

I keep getting the following errors and have tried different variations.  Would appreciate any suggestions!

```
$ bundle install
Gemfile syntax error on line 16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
end-of-input
gem 'sqlite3'           group :development :test
                                ^
$ bundle install
Gemfile syntax error on line 16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
end-of-input
gem 'sqlite3'           group: :development, :test
                                 ^
$ bundle install
Gemfile syntax error on line 16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
end-of-input
gem 'sqlite3'           group :development, :test
                                 ^

$ bundle install
Gemfile syntax error on line 16: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
end-of-input
gem 'sqlite3'           group :development, :test do 
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax:

```
group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

just an advise work with your production DB also in test and development.